# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotTools'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**Using jupyter notebook to run the below python code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from plotTools import *
```

**It gives the below feedback.**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
```

```
from plotTools import *
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotTools'
```

**In order to be sure that 'plotTools' is installed and up to date, the status was checked by using:**

```
pip install -U plotTools
```

**This also gives:**

```
Requirement already up-to-date: plotTools in c:\users\mathewa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.2.0)
```

**So, what else needs to be done?
Thanks**

Comment: what happens when you try to import plotTools from regular python (just open python from the command line)?

Comment: Using regular python, it works fine.

Comment: Did you try to restart the kernel in Jupyter?

Comment: Yes, I did. I restarted the kernel but it still gives the error.


Using regular python, it works fine. However, I am interested in using jupyter nootbook . Jupyter notebook will be used for the entire program as some sections have been tested and yielded good results on jupyter notebook. That's reason I am interested in making the code to work on jupyter notebook.

Comment: you're probably using different python installations. what version of python do you use in Jupyter, and what version in the command line?

Comment: I'm sure that the version of the python on the command line is 3.8. Please, how will I quickly check for the version of python in Jupyter?

Comment: run "import sys;  sys.version_info"

Comment: It yields:    sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: so ... you're running two different python installations. You installed the package for one, but have a different one in Jupyter. What OS are you running on?

Comment: I use Window 10

Comment: how did you install jupyter? Via conda?

Comment: Yes, Jupyter was installed via Anaconda

Comment: I would try to run conda install plotTools. See if it helps.

Comment: I have been trying the option but yet to get a positive result.

Comment: Did it install successfully? Did you restart the kernel after that?

Comment: I removed the Jupyter which was installed by conda and then used pip to install it. This is to be sure that the same installation has been used for both regular python and Jupyter. Nevertheless, the code yields the same error on Jupyter but it runs well on regular python.

Comment: Did you verify that the version within Jupyter is the same one you're getting in the command line?